# How to position three div elements side by side across a webpage

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hi all Iam trying to build a website that has a 'div container' and within this div three main columns, 'div left', 'div middle' and 'div right'.

I have tried to set the width for each column to 25%, 50%, and 25% respectively - also floated all divs left - with two images either side of the table (div middle). Unfortunately the three divs are on separate lines instead of side by side. Has anyone got any tips or advice for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: The middle div (holding the table) is populated as events are added.

```
<div id = "container" style = "width:100%">

<div id ="left" style = "float: left; width: 25%;">
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('/img/sideart.jpg'); ?>
</div>

    <div id = "middle" style = "float: center; width: 50%; height: 100%;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>

    </tr>

    <?php
    foreach ($events as $event): ?>

    <tr>
        <td class="actions">

        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div id = "right" style = "float:right; width: 25%;">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('/img/sideart2.jpg'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `float:center;`

Comment: Just `float:left;` all of them. If you don't have any margin/padding/borders on these divs, they will fill the width of the page perfectly.\

Comment: I see no reason to close this question.

Comment: The only thing you need is float: left as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sag2W/. Remember that if you add borders you can not have the divs in the size of 25%, 50% and 25%.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<div id = "container" style = "width:100%">
    <div id ="left" style = "float:left; width: 25%;">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('/img/sideart.jpg'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id = "middle" style = "float:left; width: 50%;">

    </div>
    <div id = "right" style = "float:left; width: 25%;">

    </div>
</div>
```

There is no such thing as float:center. By floating them all left they will line up next to each other.

Comment: This also works for 4 divs, if you set `width` to 25%. Found many solutions, finally something works! The Cage players thank you Cory! Cage is were we play ( google cage samaras for more :P ). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things are going on here.

`<div>` is a block-level element.  This means, by default you will get a newline after each one. (The CSS would be `display: block`).

You can make them not do newlines, but retain their spacing characteristic by doing:

```
display: inline-block
```

This will make them display inline, but allow for vertical spacing as if they were block level elements.

You were right to try to `float` them but due to how the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) works, any `margin` or `border` attribute will cause them to be larger than the percentages you've specified.  (Edit: missed that `float: center` -- that doesn't exist.  It's `right` or `left` for `float`.)

You might try to specify widths that total less than 100% as well if you want to continue to float them.

Comment: Not a fan on inline-block because of no IE7 support without adding other hacks

Comment: @MatthewCox If you're still supporting IE7, I feel sorry for you. It's market share is less than 1% at this point, it doesn't support a ton of CSS functionality, and has horrible JavaScript support. We've dropped support for it on all our apps (as well as my last four companies did as well, a mix of small start-ups and multinational media conglomerates.)  But you are right, `inline-block` will not work in IE7. Nor Netscape 4.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to support IE7 you don't need to float anything.  Given this markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        First Div
    </div>
    <div>
        Middle Div
    </div>
    <div>
        Last Div
    </div>
</div>
```

This CSS will give you three columns 25%/50%/25%:

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
}
#container > div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/Hvtqh/).